# sscanf() with newline as delimiter

Tags: c++, c

In the following code, `scanf()` will split the string on the encounter of any whitespace:

```
char str[] = "Hello I'm Tom";

char token1[256];
char token2[256];
char token3[256];

sscanf(str, "%s%s%s", token1, token2, token3);
```

Can I make it only split the string on the encounter of a newline (`\n`)?

Comment: Given that input string, should we assume you plan on checking the result of the `sscanf` invoke to know how many parameters you actually fulfilled (if any)?

Comment: `char *sptr = strtok(str, "\r\n");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `istringstream::getline`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  std::istringstream input("Hello I'm Tom\nHello I'm Jim\nHello I'm Tim");
  char token1[256];
  char token2[256];
  char token3[256];
  input.getline(token1, 256);
  input.getline(token2, 256);
  input.getline(token3, 256);
  cout << token1 << endl;
  cout << token2 << endl;
  cout << token3 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf()` as below:

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",comment);
```

But try to use [fgets](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/gets.3.html) instead.

```
fgets(comment, sizeof comment, stdin);
```

Or use `gets()` or `getline()` functions to read string from `stdin`.

Comment: Because you'll get a warning in most modern libc's. That warning is for a reason: gets() contains a security flaw. Quoting the man page: "Because it is impossible to tell without knowing the data in advance how many characters gets() will read, and because gets() will continue to store characters past the end of the buffer, it is extremely dangerous to use.  It has been used to break computer security.  Use fgets() instead."